# binary search tree find item pair with fixed cost algorithm

Tags: data-structures

a binary search tree is given, containing price for n items,(one price for each item), no two price are the same. Suppose I have m dollars, find a pair of two items with exact total cost m. Write an O(n) algorithm.

Can someone tell me how to finish it in O(n)

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-a-pair-with-given-sum-in-bst/

Comment: *Can someone tell me how to finish it in O(n)*sure many people here can help you. But can you show us the code you have so far